# iOS OpenCV haarcascade for other facial emotions

Tags: ios, opencv

I have been trying OpenCV iOS sample to achieve facial emotion recognition.
I got OpenCV sample iOS project 'openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial' from below link.
https://github.com/egeorgiou/openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial/tree/master/openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial

This sample project uses 'face detection', it works fine. It uses 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml' trained model.

I want to use the same project but have haarcascade for other facial emotions like Sad, Surprise. I have been searching for how to train haarcascade for emotions like Sad, Surprise etc. but couldn't find any clue.

Could someone advise me, how to train haarcascade for emotions like Sad, Surprise etc. to use in this sample OpenCV iOS project? Or will there be readymade haarcascade for emotions like Sad, Surprise etc. to use for this iOS sample.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can read [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) on how to generate haarcascade file, but generating haarcascade for emotions is not easy task.

I would suggest to extract Mouth and eye from face and using haarcascade and process these rectangles for detecting emotions. you can get gaarcascade for mouth and eye from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) . Mouth and Eye are complicated feature so will not work if you will try to find it in whole image, so first find the front face and try to detect mouth and eye within face rectangle only.

There are open source library available on [github](https://github.com/liy9393/emotion-detection/blob/master/readme.txt) for emotion detaction, though these are not for ios, you can use similar algorithm to implement in ios.

Comment: Hi, Can you please come to chat to discuss more. I have some more doubts on this.

Comment: Can I get some iOS sample for this -> "I would suggest to extract Mouth and eye from face and using haarcascade and process these rectangles for detecting emotions."

Comment: There is not any iOS Sample as per my knowledge for whole process. You need to do it. You can detect Mouth and Eye the way you are detecting face. Then using detected Rect, crop your face image to Mouth and Eye. And then Apply processing on these images to detect emotions.  for emotion detection , here is algorithm : https://github.com/liy9393/emotion-detection/blob/master/readme.txt

Comment: I am asking if any iOS sample there for just extracting face and mouth and eye. With that I can start with to work further on emotion detection.

Comment: @Stella Ok..Even for that, I am not aware if any. You can get hear cascade files from Mouth and eye from http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34  and use these files in demo which you are using, https://github.com/egeorgiou/openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial/tree/master/openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial. when you detect face rect, First crop Image to face rect, Now on cropped image Apply hear cascade for Mouth and eye.

Comment: BTW, You can detect Mouth , Eye and Face without using OpenCV Too for iOS, https://github.com/nacho4d/FaceDetectionExample2

Comment: and here is blog for detecting smile: http://idevelopersmalltalk.blogspot.in/2013/10/face-smiling-and-blinking-detection-on.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I have tried native iOS smile detection earlier, it worked for me. But I want to around 6 - 7 emotion detection. iOS native doesn't support for that. FaceDetectionExample2 sample is not working. I'll try to use OpenCV, reading documentation. It will be even more helpful if SVM based emotion detection samples available.