# Creating a Haar cascade that can be implemented in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm working on an iOS application that involves object detection (in this case, the eye) using OpenCV. How can I create a Haar cascade that I can implement into my iOS application? I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903906/ios-opencv-haarcascade-for-other-facial-emotions), but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of `opencv_contrib` `face module`, [~\face\data\cascades](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face/data/cascades), comes with pre-trained face detection data which included below features.

- left and right ears (`haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_rightear.xml`)
- left and right eyes (`haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml`)
- eye pair (`haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml`)
- mouth (`haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml`)
- nose (`haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml`)
- upper body (`haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml`)

You can use them in your code to build your `iOS` application. There are samples and tutorials in [~\face](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face).